# Por que não podemos ser gentis?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Sou um usuário novo no SO, mas faço parte de diversos fóruns e comunidades dos mais mais variados assuntos.

Sempre que trato com os colegas dos fóruns tento ser o mais educado possível: Início dando um bom dia/boa tarde/boa noite e, principalmente quando faço uma pergunta, encerro agradecendo pelo tempo que os colegas vão dispender para ajudar a solucionar um problema que, a priori, nem é deles.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Na maioria das vezes minhas questões aqui são editadas e removidos as saudações e os agradecimentos finais. Por que não podemos ser gentis com os colegas que estão nos fazendo um favor sem ganhar nada em troca? Por que temos que ser robóticos e não demonstrar educação com o próximo?

Confesso que essa questão me incomoda um pouco, pois acho que com educação podemos fazer uma comunidade melhor, mesmo que sejam esses pequenos gestos.

Existe uma diretiva do SO que pregue essa coisa de ir direto ao ponto?

Comment: Somos gentis quando respondemos com todo o carinho e dedicação a uma dúvida. A questão talvez seja porque você confunda certas formalidades do dia-a-dia como parte inerente ao diálogo, principalmente à função da linguagem feita para testar o canal de comunicação. Como nosso canal de comunicação funciona, ele não precisa ser testado como no caso do contato pessoal, por isso que cumprimentos e saudações acabam sendo removidos. No final, como a finalidade deles é testar para saber se há canal de comunicação criado, ele simplesmente acaba introduzindo ruído desnecessário...

Comment: ... Se a pessoa responde ou comenta à sua publicação, então possa ter certeza de que houve a comunicação. Assim sendo, verificar se há comunicação é redundante e desnecessário, voltando mais energia do autor a produzir um conteúdo de qualidade do que a testar se há comunicação (função primária da função de linguagem fática) ou seguir um protocolo ou etiqueta presumida por grupos sociais (função secundária da função de linguagem fática)

Comment: Gentileza é um conceito complicado, e cada um tem a sua. Por exemplo, dar bom dia para uma pessoa que está lendo na parte da tarde não é nada gentil. Fazer ações sem pensar, mecanicamente, não é gentil. Na verdade quando a pessoa tem pensamento crítico ela entende que este tipo de coisa é feita com intuito de obter vantagem, de criar um clima amistoso para facilitar que a pessoa atenda seus interesses. A não ser quando é genuíno, o que é raro transparecer que seja. Quase todo "bom dia" é mecânico, o próprio emissor não percebe que é uma ação subliminar. Como disse o Jefferson, é formalidade.

Comment: Dar "bom dia" e engatar a pergunta não faz sentido, o erro é os outros locais onde se faz isto. Em comunicações assíncronas e abertas é errado fazer este tipo de coisa. Nosso modelo é de perguntas e respostas. É como se fosse uma prova. Seu professor escrever "bom dia" em cada pergunta que ele te faz? Você faz o mesmo em cada pergunta? Não faz sentido. Gentileza é preocupação real com a pessoa, tem diversas formas de expressar isto, e algo mecânico não o faz, por isso assino em baixo do que foi dito pelo @JeffersonQuesado.

Comment: A parte legal é que notou isto. A maioria dos usuários nem nota que não se deve fazer isto, não muda a atitude, não entende as regras da casa, eles acham que eles podem fazer do jeito deles. Isto não é ser gentil. Tem gente que acha que ser gentil é deixar o fumante fumar dentro de sua casa, tem gente que acha que ser gentil é não fumar na casa dos outros. Tem gente que acha que perguntar antes de fumar é ser gentil, quando na verdade está criando um constrangimento e obrigando a pessoa ser gentil e deixar, mas a gentileza aí é não dizer "não". Tudo fica errado.

Comment: Uma das coisas mais legais do SO é que incentiva as pessoas fazerem o certo. Se elas aprenderão fazer é outra estória, mas pelo menos aqui somos questionadores, tentamos fazer o mais correto possível. Então robótico é fazer sempre o mesmo sem pensar, sem entender o contexto, é funcionar como robôs. E sim, a maioria dos humanos funcionam como robôs, elas aprendem certas regras e não entendem porque. Ou seja, ela crescem usando "boas práticas", programações que foram aprendendo, elas não o fazem por livre arbítrio. Claro, tem quem discorde, mas, pare, pense, deixe de lado o que sempre acreditou.

Comment: Os fóruns da rede StackExchange não são fóruns onde pessoas "trocam mensagens". Este modelo de fórum é feito para servir de enciclopédia, referência e absolutamente sobre ser objetivo. O chat é mais informal, e pode usar de floreios e outros artefatos da gentileza; mas as perguntas/respostas são sim, objetivas. Inclusive é por isso que perguntas como "não consigo resolver exercício XYZ da faculdade" são desencorajadas ou até proibidas em alguns casos. Ainda, se desejar agradecer, pode fazê-lo nos comentários após receber ajuda.

Comment: hahahaha ironicamente meus cumprimentos dessa postagem foram removidos. Resumindo, não se deve nem mesmo agradecer na postagem? Como vou seguiu usando o SO concordo com as regras e irei acatar, mas reitero que não vejo um "muito obrigado" como ruído, mas sim como um mero agradecimento por fulano parar tudo que estava fazendo e tentar resolver meu problema.

Comment: @Max use o voto positivo e marque a resposta como aceita ou ofereça uma recompensa a mais para expressar seu agradecimento :)

Comment: @Max imagine um monte de obrigado e bom dia no meio da wikipedia. Queremos que o conteúdo seja objetivo como lá, por isso desincentivamos o formato de diálogo. Mas como já foi dito, pode deixar agradecimentos nos comentários, por exemplo. Só não dê muita bola se depois de algum tempo esses comentários sumirem.